# create large matrix from two small matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have two matrices (5_by_1), say A=[5 rows,1 column] and B=[5 rows, 1 column] if I do `plot(A,B)`, I will create a large matrix  C=[5 rows,5 columns] wright?!

Now I would like to create this large matrix without plot it. I want this matrix directly.
thank you.
For example 
A=[1 2 3 4 5 ] and B=[3 4 2 1 4]

c=

```
 0     1     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share? What did you try already?

Comment: For instance, A=[1 2 3 4 5] and B=[3 4 2 1 3], when I plot it plot(A,B,'*'). I will get a graph with points in different positions. I shared one example in my question now.

Comment: This question is answered here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495360/generate-plot-matrix-from-two-different-matrices-in-matlab][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495360/generate-plot-matrix-from-two-different-matrices-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

If the plot is creating A * Transpose(B) you could always use `C = A * B'`

Comment: Hi, thank you. But this doesn't work, I shared one example now which explain what c should look like. thank you again for your response