# generate plot matrix from two different matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have two matrices (5_by_1), say A=[5 rows,1 column] and B=[5 rows, 1 column] if I do plot(A,B), I will create a large matrix C=[5 rows,5 columns] wright?!

Now I would like to create this large matrix without plot it. I want this matrix directly. thank you. 
For example `A=[1 2 3 4 5 ]` and `B=[3 4 2 1 4]`

```
c=

 0     1     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5];
b = [3 4 2 1 4];

c = flipud(sparse(b,a,1,4,5));
```

If you want to see the full c:

```
full(c)
```

or if you have a bigger version:

```
c = flipud(sparse(b,a,1,max(b),max(a)));
```

The `flipud` command is to flip the matrix upside down.

Hope this helps =)

**EDIT:**

"Shift" the matrices, so that your lowest value is in (1,1) (before you flip it). The structure will be correct, but the origin won't be easy to spot.

```
a_1 = floor(a - min(a)) + 1;  % floor if you don't have integers.
b_1 = floor(b - min(b)) + 1;

c = flipud(sparse(b_1,a_1,1,max(b_1),max(a_1)));
```

Comment: Hi, many thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks for your response, but I got this message:??? Error using ==> sparse
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> test at 3
c=flipud(sparse(B,A,1,4,5));

Comment: It works for me... Have you tried copying my answer directly into Matlab? 
The code I provided is only valid if: A is a 1:n matrix ([1 2 3...n]). Try the version below (with max() etc.) I have updated it a bit.

Comment: it works only for integers and positive numbers. but my real matrix contains zeros and negative number..

this is the error now(Sparse matrix sizes must be non-negative integers less than MAXSIZE as defined by COMPUTER.  Use HELP
COMPUTER for more details.)

Comment: In that case, you need to decide a few things: How do you want to handle negative numbers and zeros? Since you can't use these as indices to a matrix, you might want to "shift" the matrix so that your lowest value is in position (1,1), before you flip it. It will make it hard to know where the origin is, but at least the structure will be correct.

Comment: Ok, I can manage my negative numbers by adding abs(-20). but if I have for instance 1.782 !! if I use round(1.782) my whole matrix numbers will change. that is the undesirable thing :(. is there any way to avoid it ?!

Comment: the main idea for me is to avoid integer numbers :( :( :(.. it should be fractions

Comment: What do you mean be "avoid" integer numbers? You can't using decimal numbers as indices. If you have a common denominator, you can multiply by it, if not, you would need to round of your numbers. (As far as I know).